# Wrong usage of “myself ”, or just putting emphasis on “me”?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, syntactic-analysis, emphasis, reflexives

I was writing the following sentence, and I realized it somehow sounds odd:

> I am constantly trying to remind myself to think carefully before speaking, but those moments I forget to do so end up hurting others and **myself**.

Does it sound somewhat awkward, and if so, how would I have to change it?

> I am constantly trying to remind myself to think carefully before speaking. However, there are few moments where I forget to do so, and end up hurting others and myself.

Could above be an alternative? but is there a way to write it in one sentence, putting emphasis on *me*, and still not making it sound odd?

Comment: "To remind myself" is fine.  In your context, "To remind me" would be odd.  As for the latter example, I would probably write "as well as myself" instead of "and myself".

Comment: @Ste It is not the first *myself* that is the problem.

Comment: @tchrist - Good observation.  My answer stands though.

Comment: The entire sentence is awkward because *"those moments"* can't "end up" doing or being anything. They're "moments" which after taking place, remain *in the past*. Only things like *people*, or *ongoing situations*, can "end up" in any later (different) state from how they started.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that if the sentence is analyzed strictly by logic, it sounds quite odd. But does it necessarily sound very odd if you use it casually in real life? I mean, if I directly translate it in Korean (I'm Korean, by the way), it doesn't sound awkward, but just expressive. I'm not sure how an English native speaker would find it normally.

Comment: @Mika: It seems immediately "odd" to me - but I can't very well say every native speaker would think the same, since as far as I can see no-one else has remarked on it. Personally I'd be quite happy if you'd used *"times"* rather than *"moments"*, since to me *"a time"* means *"an episode"*, which extends from when the sequence of interconnected events starts, to when it ends. I personally don't think *"a moment"* can extend over time like that, but others may feel differently.

Comment: ...I would also say that to me, it's not really possible to *"**try to** remind yourself"* of anything. Either you do or you don't. It's more common to say *"I **have to** remind myself"* - where I come from, at least.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Thanks for your comment! I see English follows more strict syntactic rules. It's interesting to see how one expression can be well understood in one language, but not so well in another. I guess I have to read more English texts and get used to their way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am constantly trying to remind myself to think carefully before
>   speaking, but those moments I forget to do so end up hurting others
>   and myself.

Your use of *myself* didn’t strike me as especially odd, at all. The only quibble I do have with the way you've written it is that you've set it up so that it’s *those moments* that hurt others. In fact, it’s *you* who are hurting others. So, try this:

> I am constantly trying to remind myself to think carefully before
>   speaking, but in those moments when I forget to do so, I end up
>   hurting others and myself.

Or this:

> I am constantly trying to remind myself to think carefully before
>   speaking, but when I forget to do so, I end up hurting others
>   and myself.

Comment: You don’t think this use of *myself* is odd?  Really?  So it doesn’t bother you to use reflexives unreflexively then?

Comment: Hi @tchrist, no, not at all. "...myself and others" might be slightly more conventional, or "...others as well as myself."

Comment: @tchrist It doesn't strike me as odd either - certainly not *especially* odd. It *does* strike me as formally incorrect, which is something different.

Comment: @StoneyB Arnold’s article is interesting, isn’t it?

Comment: @tchrist Yes it is; but I'm not convinced that 'logophoricity' is in play in English - it's new to me as of this page. I think most of what he describes (and the sentence Mika questions) represents ordinary errors of what I call 'semi-formal' English: people engaging in discourse which calls for formal English without taking (or being allowed) the time to edit. I work with it a lot in excerpting videotaped interviews with corporate panjandrums (panjandra?).

Answer (score 2):

You could reverse the order at the end: *hurting myself and others*.

On the other hand, your perceived notion of awkwardness might stem from realizing that this is actually a proscribed use of *myself* for some people, because the subject and object fail to agree.  You have *moments* as the subject, but *myself* as the object.  You might make that easier by saying that the moments end up hurting others and me myself, using an emphatic not a reflexive version.

See [this Language Log posting](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/003215.html) by linguist Arnold Zwicky regarding ***logophoric*** uses of reflexive pronouns in English.